# Capture the n previous words when matching a string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have this text:

```
abcdefg Mark Jones (PP) etc etc
akslaskAS Taylor Daniel Lautner (PMB) blabla
etcetc Allan Stewart Konigsberg Farrow (PRTW)
```

I want to capture these personal names:

> Mark Jones, Taylor Daniel Lautner, Allan Stewart Konigsberg Farrow.

Basically, when we find **(P** followed by any capital letter, we capture the n previous words that start with a capital letter.

What I have achieved so far is to capture just one previous word with this code: `\w+(?=\s+(\(P+[A-Z]))`. But I couldn't evolve from that.
I appreciate it if someone can help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regex pattern**

```
\b((?:[A-Z]\w+\s?)+)\s\(P[A-Z]
```

In order to find all matching occurrences of the above regex pattern we can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import re

text = """abcdefg Mark Jones (PP) etc etc
akslaskAS Taylor Daniel Lautner (PMB) blabla
etcetc Allan Stewart Konigsberg Farrow (PRTW)
"""

matches = re.findall(r'\b((?:[A-Z]\w+\s?)+)\s\(P[A-Z]', text)
```

---

```
>>> matches
['Mark Jones', 'Taylor Daniel Lautner', 'Allan Stewart Konigsberg Farrow']
```

**Regex details**

- `\b` : Word boundary to prevent partial matches
- `((?:[A-Z]\w+\s?)+)`: First Capturing group

  - `(?:[A-Z]\w+\s?)+`: Non capturing group matches one or more times

    - `[A-Z]`: Matches a single alphabet from capital `A` to `Z`
    - `\w+`:  Matches any word character one or more times
    - `\s?` : Matches any whitespace character zero or one times
- `\s` : Matches a single whitespace character
- `\(`: Matches the character `(` literally
- `P` : Matches the character `P` literally
- `[A-Z]` : Matches a single alphabet from capital `A` to `Z`

See the online [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/yZNFEM/1)

Comment: Your answer worked very well! But I ran into a new problem: names like "Juan di Lorenzo" or "Luca dos Santos" are not fully captured because these prepositions are not capitalized. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Using Python's `re` library here to fetch the results. Firstly using `findall` to fetch all values from given string var where `(.*?)\s+\((?=P[A-Z])` will catch everything which is having P and a capital letter after it, then creating a list lst. Later using substitute function to substitute everything non-spacing things followed by spaces 1st occurrences with NULL to get exact values.

```
import re
var="""abcdefg Mark Jones (PP) etc etc
akslaskAS Taylor Daniel Lautner (PMB) blabla
etcetc Allan Stewart Konigsberg Farrow (PRTW)"""

lst = re.findall(r'(.*?)\s+\((?=P[A-Z])',var)
[re.sub(r'^\S+\s+','',s) for s in lst]
```

Output will be as follows:

```
['Mark Jones', 'Taylor Daniel Lautner', 'Allan Stewart Konigsberg Farrow']
```

Comment: I think just `findall` can do the job, just start matches from capital letters.

Comment: @anubhava, thank you sir for your nice suggestion. I actually considered it but then I thought if in case anything is not starting from capital letter, hence I went with this approach.